# Salt External Pillar Issues

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to configure an external pillar in github, but no matter what I cannot get the minions to successfully read top.sls. Below is my ext_pillar and pillar_roots config:

```
pillar_roots:
  base:
  - /srv/pillar
fileserver_backend:
  - gitfs
  - roots
gitfs_update_interval: 60
gitfs_base: main
gitfs_remotes:
  - https://gituser:gittoken@github.com/gitaccount/saltstack.git:
    - mountpoint: salt://
ext_pillar:
  - git:
    - main https://gituser:gittoken@github.com/gitaccount/saltpillar.git
```

I have the following in the root of my `saltpillar` repo:

top.sls:

```
base:
  '*':
    - data
```

data.sls:

```
info: some test data from remote pillar
```

Repos are accessible with the URIs provided. When I run `salt '*' saltutil.refresh_pillar` and then `salt '*' pillar.items` I get no results. However, I can put top.sls and data.sls directly into /srv/pillar and it works. I put the master in debug mode and don't see any errors running the commands. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out. I think I am in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following `ext_pillar` configuration fix your issue? I'm assuming your top.sls you posted is still in the `main` branch of your git repo.

```
ext_pillar:
  - git:
    - main https://gituser:gittoken@github.com/gitaccount/saltpillar.git
      - env: base
```

Your top.sls must reference your actual branch name or you can add the `env` option to specify a different name.

https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.git_pillar.html