# Salt GitFS and Pillar Checkout location

Tags: salt-stack

I am wondering for for both GitFS file systems and GIT Pillar, where are those files checked out? I don't seem to be able to locate them on my system.

My issue might be related to this: [Salt External Pillar Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72356277/salt-external-pillar-issues)

Answer (score 0):

`/var/cache/salt/master/gitfs` and `/var/cache/salt/master/git_pillar`